# How to manage users' orphaned processes?

Tags: services, daemon, process-management

I have a service that executes users' scripts which in turn spawn more processes. Some of those processes stop on external conditions that might not take place. Since the the parent is gone (e.g. may crash), how can anybody else know `PID` of the orphaned process to stop it?

1. Is there any reliable way to store `PID` so that it is not overwritten by mistake?
2. If "PID file" is the only option, should it be writable by designated per-process user as a convention?
3. Should I ban using shared account so that users can `killall` their own processes safely?
4. Should I think of policy that will result in killing orphaned processes immediately so that scripts are forced to manage them reliably?

Comment: _Since the the parent is gone_ - OMG, zombies! :)

Comment: shared accounts are a terrible idea anyway.  If multiple users need access to shared files, that's what groups (or ACLs) are for (along with `umask 002` and setgid (`chmod g+rws`) on group **directories**).  So yes to 3.